# Reopen queue edit history incorrectly escapes HTML

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues

I'll cut to the chase and just attach screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

It seems pretty clear that the text in the "Comment" column of the history since question closure is incorrectly escaped HTML code. Here are a couple of items in the reopen votes review queue that show this behavior: [one](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29430475), [two](https://stackoverflow.com/review/reopen/29432930).

Comment: someone seems to have assigned HTML to `textContent` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will be fixed in the next build.

There are actually two problems here, one making the other more obvious.  The first is that we shouldn't be showing non-edit revisions in the list.  They're throwing off the count and the link in the date goes to a 404 page.

The second is that the comment contains raw HTML but we're escaping it.  In most of the codebase, HTML is stored in `IHtmlContent` implementations.  These render as-is by ASP.Net whereas `string` get escaped.  This offers XSS defense along with type checking.  Revision comments are one of the exceptions on the TODO list for conversion.  They need to be explicitly wrapped in a `IHtmlContent` at render time to avoid double-escaping.