# Remove duplicate updates from the edit history in the queue

Tags: bug, duplicate-questions, revision-history

I didn't find a suitable title but here is a screenshot to illustrate:

> [image]

The strange numbers you see there (`from 1817792 - to 1817792,4502633`) is my duplicate list edit and I don't think it's relevant to have such thing there.

We should either remove it or update the comment to make the action more clear so people understand what I did.

Answer (score 5):

I think the history entry *is* useful, *if* it were formatted differently.
At very least, it should mention *"duplicate targets"*:

> Duplicate target(s) changed from 123 to 456, 789

Or maybe even show the question titles in there.

Comment: at least like in the timeline: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/68532936/timeline

Comment: Yea, that's perfect.

Comment: I also think the post history is *extremely* useful. But it's new and there are still a few minor glitches that need to be fixed (like the bad HTML escaping, posted [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/409312/10871073)).